# Galois Group of $x^{12}+x^{11}+\dots+x^2+x+1$

Tags: galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

It seems I have forgot all the details about the group theory. Anyone knows what is the Galois Group of $x^{12}+x^{11}+\dots+x^2+x+1$ and is that solvable?

Thanks.

Comment: It is the $13$'th cyclotomic polynomial.

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

$$x^{12} + \ldots + x + 1 = \frac{x^{13} - 1}{x - 1}$$

The galois groups of $\,x^p-1\;$ over the rationals is isomorphic with $\,\left(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\right)^*\;$ and thus has order equal to $\,\phi(p)=p-1\;$

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean the roots cannot be presented using radicals?

Comment: @user85356: What would it mean that?

Comment: The galois group is cyclic, thus solvable.

Comment: @user85356 The roots CAN be presented using radicals. The roots are basically the roots of unity which are presentable using radicals.

Comment: @yanbo Thanks. Is it possible to get those explitc radicals formula for this 13-th root of unity?

Comment: @user85356 Well, it is just $(1)^{1/13}$

Comment: I mean all the roots.

Comment: @user85356 isn't just $(1)^{k/13}$ where $k$ runs from 1 to 12?

Comment: If you wish to get roots in the form of $a + ib$ where $a, b$ are real and algebraic then it is bit difficult to do so, but possible. Gauss solved these cyclotomic equations beatifully in Disquistiones Arithmeticae. In this case $12 = 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2$ and hence it is possible to get roots via solution of 2 quadratic and 1 cubic equation.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh How?

Comment: To user85356: This is based on theory of Gaussian periods. You will have to read http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2009/12/gauss-and-regular-polygons-gaussian-periods.html This is one of most interesting gems found by Gauss when he was very young (I think 17-18 yrs).

Comment: [Gauss: All roots of unity are solvable by radicals.](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2008/03/gauss-proof-that-all-roots-of-unity-are.html)